# Is there a method or plugin that will allow posts to be sortable by Facebook likes?

Tags: facebook

I'm just wondering if anyone knows of a method or plugin that I can implement that will keep track of Facebook likes within Wordpress posts, and allow me to show posts in order of "most liked"?

Comment: How, in your case/plugin, are facebook likes stored with the post data? As post meta? You'll need to provide more specific data to get some serious answer. Facebook API is external and nothing that's built in into wp.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Similar question: [Top 3 posts in last week ordered by Facebook and Twitter share counts](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/7010/top-3-posts-in-last-week-ordered-by-facebook-and-twitter-share-counts)

Basically, you have to write something to get the like count and store it as metadata with the posts every so often. Then you can order based on that count.