# Adding a "most liked post" box, based on facebook ranking?

Tags: facebook

I would like to have a list of my most liked posts from facebook, and place it in the sidebar.  Is there a way for doing it? (and if so, how?)

Answer (score 3):

A quick google [brought up these](http://www.google.co.uk/search?q=facebook%20api%20most%20liked%20pages), which led me to [this post](http://forums.digitalpoint.com/showthread.php?t=1865119#post14651844).

> 1. You can access the site's object in the Graph and get the current "Fan
>      count". i.e.
>      http://graph.facebook.com/http://google.com.
>      <strike>Note that you will need an oauth token
>      to do this.</strike> This is definitely the
>      most accurate way of getting a page's
>      Likes.
> 2. You can also use the javascript SDK to detect when a user clicks the Like
>      button and then make an ajax call in
>      the background to a php page that adds
>      to a counter or does whatever you want
>      it to. You can also detect when a user
>      Unlikes a page too.

In other words, 1) queries Facebook for the number of likes, 2) suggests to hook into the 'liking' action, counting & logging the 'likes' on your site.

<strike>Either way you're going to need to get stuck in to the [Facebook API](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/). If you go for 1), you'll also need the [PHP SDK](https://github.com/facebook/php-sdk).</strike>

I'd say 1) would be the better of the two, since it's non-JavaScript dependent, and getting 'likes' from other sources won't affect it (i.e. people liking your page using means other than the button on *your* site).

Since it looks like you can only query one page (URL) at a time (unless a Facebook guru can correct me?), you'd need some way of frequently caching the like counts of all your posts.

Perhaps a `wp_cron` function that continually loops over say, 20 posts, every hour (check Facebook usage terms), and updates the like count as a post meta entry.

To get the 'most liked' posts, you could then simply query posts that have the meta key, and order by the meta value.

```
new WP_Query( array( 'meta_key' => 'like_count', 'orderby' => 'meta_value_num', 'posts_per_page' => 5 ) );
```

Answer (score 2):

You can stick https://graph.facebook.com/ in front of any URL to see how many people liked it. It returns a JSON object with the URL and the number of "shares" for the URL.

Note: An OAuth token is *not* required to do this. You don't even have to be logged into Facebook.

Example: https://graph.facebook.com/http://ottopress.com/2011/photo-gallery-primer/

Over time, you can poll those, store the info as meta data, and then order by it.

Related question: [Top 3 posts in last week ordered by Facebook and Twitter share counts](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/7010/top-3-posts-in-last-week-ordered-by-facebook-and-twitter-share-counts)

Comment: thanks for the pointers, this was quoted from an old forum post - I am *not*, by any means, an expert on FB ;)